# How to retrieve class of generic argument in a CDI producer?

Tags: java, generics, cdi

I have a Java class with a generic type. In the business logic of that class, I need to refer to the `Class` object of the generic type. Therefore, the constructor get the `Class` object passed as argument:

```
public class MyClass<GENERIC_TYPE>{
    private Class<GENERIC_TYPE> genericTypeClass;

    public MyClass(Class<GENERIC_TYPE> genericTypeClass){
        this.genericTypeClass=genericTypeClass;
    }
}
```

I create the instance(s) of this class using a CDI producer, whose squeleton looks like

```
public class MyClassProducer{
    @Produces
    MyClass<GENERIC_TYPE> createMyClass(InjectionPoint injectionPoint){
        Class<GENERIC_TYPE> genericTypeClass = ????
        return new MyClass(genericTypeClass);
    }
}
```

How do I retrieve `genericTypeClass` ?

Comment: If you know answer on the questions, why you ask?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is a two liner:

```
public class MyClassProducer {
    @Produces
    <GENERIC_TYPE> MyClass<GENERIC_TYPE> createMyClass(InjectionPoint injectionPoint){
        final ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) injectionPoint.getType();
        final Class<GENERIC_TYPE> genericTypeClass = 
            (Class<GENERIC_TYPE>) parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        return new MyClass(genericTypeClass);
    }
}
```