# How to retrieve class of generic argument in a CDI producer when there are multiple generic class in the tree?

Tags: java, generics, cdi

Consider 3 classes.

```
public class A<TYPE> {
    private Class<TYPE> typeClass;
}

public class B<TYPE> {
    @Inject
    private A<TYPE> a;
}

public class C {
    @Inject
    private B<String> b
}
```

I want to write a CDI producer for `A` that sets the `typeClass` field of `A` to the class of the generic type, `String` in this case.

Partial solution is https://stackoverflow.com/a/36833293/1448419

It does not work in this particular case, as the `InjectionPoint` does not seem to have the necessary information.

Any chance to solve that elegantly ?

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138625/restricted-generics-with-cdi